# How to eliminate null valued cells from a CSV dataset using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, null

Each row represents a person(315 total) and each column represent a choice scenario(16 total). Each person responded randomly to 4 consecutive choice scenarios. I want to have four columns consecutively having the responses of each person and do away with any blank cell.[`Image of the excel sheet`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKYkk.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Book2.csv")
for (r,c) in df.iterrows():
if df.iat[r,c] is not None:
    for i in range(4):
        print(str(df.iat[r,c+i]))
```

**UPDATE**
I have managed to get data row wise into a list and grouped them in groups of 4 (as i need it). Now how do I keep the elements with values other than ' '?

```
import csv
rowdata = []
with open(r'C:\Users\ARPLAB31\Desktop\SPdata.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    rowdata = list(reader)
r= []
for i in range(1,718,1):
    for j in range(28):
        if len(rowdata[i][j])!=0:
            r.append(rowdata[i][j])
cardref = [r[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(r),4)] '''cardref contains the partitioned data.'''
print(cardref)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'CC', 'AA', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Provide your code snippet, for people to better understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use df.isnull() [ where df is pandas dataframe]

A good resource to find the null value in dataframe in pandas.

https://dzone.com/articles/pandas-find-rows-where-columnfield-is-null

Answer (score 0):

You can read each row, obtain the not null fields, and create a new CSV from there.

For example:

```
data = ",,2,2,2,2,,,"
arr = filter(None, data.split(",")) #removes null fields
",".join(arr) #"2,2,2,2"
```

Comment: **UPDATE**
I have managed to get data row wise into a list and grouped them in groups of 4 (as i need it). Now how do I keep the elements with values other than ' '?

Comment: import csv
    rowdata = []
    with open(r'C:\Users\ARPLAB31\Desktop\SPdata.csv') as inputfile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
        rowdata = list(reader)
    r= []
    for i in range(1,718,1):
        for j in range(28):
            if len(rowdata[i][j])!=0:
                r.append(rowdata[i][j])
    cardref = [r[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(r),4)] '''cardref contains the partitioned data.'''
    print(cardref)

Comment: **OUTPUT:**

[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'CC', 'AA', 'CC'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['CC', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC']]

Comment: `lst = [x for x in lst if x != tst1]` where `lst` is your output and `tst1 = ['','','','']`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I happened to solve my problem with the help of all the above comments. Please mention any changes to the code in the comment.

```
import pandas
import csv
rowdata = []

''' READING CSV INTO LIST'''

with open('FILE.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    rowdata = list(reader)

'''RECORDING THE POSITION OF NON-EMPTY ELEMENTS'''

r= []
for i in range(1,718,1):
    for j in range(28):
        if len(rowdata[i][j])!=0:
            r.append(j)
    continue

''' RE-GROUPING LIST AS LIST IN LIST'''

resp_index = [r[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(r),4)]
print(resp_index)
print(len(resp_index))

'''ELIMINATING BLANK SPACES AND STORING INTO NEW LIST'''

s= []
for i in range(1,718,1):
    for j in range(28):
        if len(rowdata[i][j])!=0:
            s.append(rowdata[i][j])

''' RE-GROUPING LIST AS LIST IN LIST'''

resp_main = [s[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(s),4)]
print(resp_main)
print(len(resp_main))
pd = pandas.DataFrame(resp_index)
pe = pandas.DataFrame(resp_main)

'''SAVING TO CSV FILES'''

pd.to_csv('INDEX.csv') 
pe.to_csv('RESPONSE.csv')
```